# Merging two directories into one virtual directory for compilation / aliasing include directories

Tags: c++

I have code that must be shared between two executables in the same project (one build command will build them both). This code contains `#ifdef` preprocessor statements which change how it works in each project (a command-line macro definition is used as a switch).

The source is *abstract* in the sense that some headers are missing. For example, the shared file `Application.cpp` might include a file called `gui/MainWindow.h` which doesn't exist int he shared directory but does exist in the executable source directory. Or it may include a file called `gui/Local.h` that does exist in the shared directory.

Essentially I need the `gui` path to be a combination of two locations.

On unix I've done this before simply by setting up a series of file links, but this project now has windows as a target (Visual Studio). Also, I am aware of how to do this using a shared directory structure and setting compiler include switches, but I'm hoping there is a simpler way.

Any ideas?

---

I use CMake for the build generation and GCC and Visual Studio as compilers.

I've already looked at defining a directory for the preprocessor, but the `#include` directive unfortunately cannot combine several tokens to create a filename. A single name works, and this might be an option to have cmake spit out macros for all the shared file names.

Answer (score 0):

I really think the simplest solution is to use include paths - have different paths for the different projects. Look at [property sheets](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a4xbdz1e%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) to share settings between projects and greatly simplify the management.

If you are using file links in unix, you could do the same in Windows with [symbolic links](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NTFS_symbolic_link).

Comment: I know of this method, but in this case it doesn't feel quite right. It'd be a huge change/divergence from the current directory structure of the project.

Comment: I would hope you could keep the directory structure the same and use include paths to include the right directories in the same way that you are looking at using #defines. Include paths would allow you to have a "gui" directory for each project as well as a shared "gui" directory for all the projects.

Comment: Currently our setup is a common include directory with sub-folders, `include/lib` To do the shared include I'd have to have directories like `include/exec_a/include/gui`, but then `exec_a` is kind of a nonsensical include, and this same structure must be repeated in the `src` directory as well. I know this will work, it just isn't so friendly to our current directory structure.

Comment: You could use symbolic links in Windows (requires Vista or 7). I've updated my answer.